# Wrong PWD when splitting window in tmux while in git diff

Tags: git, tmux, pwd

When running `git diff` in a tmux window and I split the window, I expect the newly created pane to use the same working directory. Here are my bindings to split the window:

```
unbind %
bind | split-window -h -c '#{pane_current_path}'
bind - split-window -v -c '#{pane_current_path}'
```

Everything works fine when running `git diff` from the root directory of the git repository and splitting the window, but when running `git diff` in another directory (e.g. `src/foo/bar`) and I split the window, the newly created pane has a different working directory: the git repository root directory.

Comment: does it work as expected if you just cd into another directory (e.g. `src/foo/bar`) and split the window?

Comment: Yes, when I split the window while being in `src/foo/bar`, the newly created pane has the same working directory. It seems like git changes the directory to the repository root while the diff is still being displayed.

Comment: i also guess it's git who changed the directory. tmux does not really care what process is running in the pane. it just gets the current dir of the running process.